# Including a Boolean flag column in results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to include a Boolean flag column in my results to signify the presence of an 'IN##' memo for any given client. For example, in the tables below, BOB has 2 memos in the SEC table. I want to return INFlag=1 for both rows since one of his memos contains 'IN' (I only care about 'IN' memos, hence the CASE statements that NULL everything else).

I've already tried counting in a select case, and nesting sub queries, but the best I can manage is flagging only rows with an 'IN' memo. I want to flag ALL rows of any specific client provided they have an 'IN' memo.

Two tables:

```
dbo.BASE
    id    name    image
    ==    ====    =====
    1     BOB     001
    2     RICK    002
    3     JOE     003
    4     BILL    004
    5     KEVIN   005

dbo.SEC
    id    memo    date
    ==    ====    ======
    1     IN20    4/1/19
    1     ME      1/1/18
    2     MO      1/1/18
    3     IN18    6/1/17
    3     MO      5/1/19
    4     ME      1/1/16
    5     ME      1/1/17
    5     MO      8/1/17
    5     MI      2/1/18
```

---

```
SELECT
    b.name              as [PName],
    COUNT(s.memo)       as [Memos],

    CASE
        WHEN s.memo like 'IN[0-9][0-9]'
        THEN s.memo
        ELSE NULL END
                        as [INID],
    CASE
        WHEN s.memo like 'IN[0-9][0-9]'
        THEN s.date
        ELSE NULL END
                        as [INDate],

    <<<FLAG Column [INFlag]>>>

FROM
    dbo.BASE b
    join dbo.SEC s on b.id = s.id

...
```

Expected Output:

```
PName   Memos   INID    INDate  INFlag
=====   =====   ====    ======  ======
BOB     2       IN20    4/1/19  1
BOB     2       NULL    NULL    1
RICK    1       NULL    NULL    0
JOE     2       IN18    6/1/17  1
JOE     2       NULL    NULL    1
BILL    1       NULL    NULL    0
KEVIN   3       NULL    NULL    0
KEVIN   3       NULL    NULL    0
KEVIN   3       NULL    NULL    0
```

---

Clients RICK, BILL and KEVIN do not have an 'IN' memo, so I want to flag all results for them with INFlag=0. Clients BOB and JOE do have an 'IN' memo, so any rows with their name get INFlag=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the results you want, use window functions:

```
select b.name, count(*) over (partition by id) as num_memos,
       (case when memo like 'IN%' then memo end) as INmemo,
       (case when memo like 'IN%' then date end) as INdate,
       max(case when memo like 'IN%' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name) as INlag
from base b join
     sec s
     on b.id = s.id
```

You can also add the information to each row in `base` using `EXISTS`:

```
select b.*, 
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from sec s
                          where s.id = b.id and
                                s.memo like 'IN%'
                         )
              then 1 else 0
        end) as INflag
from base b;
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. CASE WHEN EXISTS worked like a charm